# Spark on windows - Error initializing SparkContext, Invalid spark URL

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop

I'm trying to run Apache Spark on Windows 8.1
When I call the spark-shell command, I get the following stack:

```
C:\spark\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7\bin>"C:\new\spark\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7\bin\spark-submit2.cmd" --class org.apache
.spark.repl.Main --name "Spark shell"
2018-04-17 20:30:21 WARN  NativeCodeLoader:62 - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-
java classes where applicable
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
2018-04-17 20:30:33 ERROR SparkContext:91 - Error initializing SparkContext.
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Invalid Spark URL: spark://HeartbeatReceiver@Silierin_Y510P:4391
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEndpointAddress$.apply(RpcEndpointAddress.scala:66)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.asyncSetupEndpointRefByURI(NettyRpcEnv.scala:134)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRefByURI(RpcEnv.scala:101)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRef(RpcEnv.scala:109)
        at org.apache.spark.util.RpcUtils$.makeDriverRef(RpcUtils.scala:32)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.<init>(Executor.scala:155)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.local.LocalEndpoint.<init>(LocalSchedulerBackend.scala:59)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.local.LocalSchedulerBackend.start(LocalSchedulerBackend.scala:126)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.start(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:164)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:500)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2486)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$7.apply(SparkSession.scala:930)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$7.apply(SparkSession.scala:921)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:921)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.createSparkSession(Main.scala:103)
        at $line3.$read$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:15)
        at $line3.$read$$iw.<init>(<console>:43)
        at $line3.$read.<init>(<console>:45)
        at $line3.$read$.<init>(<console>:49)
        at $line3.$read$.<clinit>(<console>)
        at $line3.$eval$.$print$lzycompute(<console>:7)
        at $line3.$eval$.$print(<console>:6)
        at $line3.$eval.$print(<console>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:786)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:1047)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:638)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:637)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:31)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.AbstractFileClassLoader.asContext(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:19)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest.loadAndRunReq(IMain.scala:637)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:569)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:565)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.interpretStartingWith(ILoop.scala:807)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.command(ILoop.scala:681)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.processLine(ILoop.scala:395)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$2.a
pply(SparkILoop.scala:79)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$2.a
pply(SparkILoop.scala:79)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(SparkILoop.s
cala:79)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:79
)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:79
)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.savingReplayStack(ILoop.scala:91)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply$mcV$sp(SparkILoop.scala:78)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:78)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:78)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.beQuietDuring(IMain.scala:214)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.initializeSpark(SparkILoop.scala:77)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.loadFiles(SparkILoop.scala:110)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(ILoop.scala:920)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:909)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:909)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:97)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.process(ILoop.scala:909)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.doMain(Main.scala:76)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:56)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:879)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:197)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:227)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:136)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
2018-04-17 20:30:33 ERROR Utils:91 - Uncaught exception in thread main
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.local.LocalSchedulerBackend.org$apache$spark$scheduler$local$LocalSchedulerBackend
$$stop(LocalSchedulerBackend.scala:159)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.local.LocalSchedulerBackend.stop(LocalSchedulerBackend.scala:137)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.stop(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:508)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.stop(DAGScheduler.scala:1752)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$stop$8.apply$mcV$sp(SparkContext.scala:1924)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryLogNonFatalError(Utils.scala:1357)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.stop(SparkContext.scala:1923)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:578)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2486)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$7.apply(SparkSession.scala:930)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$7.apply(SparkSession.scala:921)
        at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:921)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.createSparkSession(Main.scala:103)
        at $line3.$read$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:15)
        at $line3.$read$$iw.<init>(<console>:43)
        at $line3.$read.<init>(<console>:45)
        at $line3.$read$.<init>(<console>:49)
        at $line3.$read$.<clinit>(<console>)
        at $line3.$eval$.$print$lzycompute(<console>:7)
        at $line3.$eval$.$print(<console>:6)
        at $line3.$eval.$print(<console>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:786)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:1047)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:638)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:637)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:31)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.AbstractFileClassLoader.asContext(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:19)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest.loadAndRunReq(IMain.scala:637)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:569)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:565)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.interpretStartingWith(ILoop.scala:807)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.command(ILoop.scala:681)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.processLine(ILoop.scala:395)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$2.a
pply(SparkILoop.scala:79)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$2.a
pply(SparkILoop.scala:79)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(SparkILoop.s
cala:79)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:79
)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:79
)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.savingReplayStack(ILoop.scala:91)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply$mcV$sp(SparkILoop.scala:78)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:78)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:78)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.beQuietDuring(IMain.scala:214)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.initializeSpark(SparkILoop.scala:77)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.loadFiles(SparkILoop.scala:110)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(ILoop.scala:920)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:909)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:909)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:97)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.process(ILoop.scala:909)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.doMain(Main.scala:76)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:56)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:879)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:197)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:227)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:136)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
2018-04-17 20:30:33 WARN  MetricsSystem:66 - Stopping a MetricsSystem that is not running
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Invalid Spark URL: spark://HeartbeatReceiver@Silierin_Y510P:4391
  at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEndpointAddress$.apply(RpcEndpointAddress.scala:66)
  at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.asyncSetupEndpointRefByURI(NettyRpcEnv.scala:134)
  at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRefByURI(RpcEnv.scala:101)
  at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRef(RpcEnv.scala:109)
  at org.apache.spark.util.RpcUtils$.makeDriverRef(RpcUtils.scala:32)
  at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.<init>(Executor.scala:155)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.local.LocalEndpoint.<init>(LocalSchedulerBackend.scala:59)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.local.LocalSchedulerBackend.start(LocalSchedulerBackend.scala:126)
  at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.start(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:164)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:500)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2486)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$7.apply(SparkSession.scala:930)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$anonfun$7.apply(SparkSession.scala:921)
  at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:921)
  at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.createSparkSession(Main.scala:103)
  ... 55 elided
<console>:14: error: not found: value spark
       import spark.implicits._
              ^
<console>:14: error: not found: value spark
       import spark.sql
              ^
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.3.0
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.11.8 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_162)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala>
```

System variables are configured as follows:

**HADOOP_HOME:**

> c:\hadoop

**JAVA_HOME:**

> C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_162

**SCALA_HOME:**

> C:\scala

**SPARK_HOME:**

> C:\spark\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7

**PATH:**

> %JAVA_HOME%\bin;%SCALA_HOME%\bin;%HADOOP_HOME%\bin;%SPARK_HOME%\bin;

spark downloaded from here:
https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html

winutils (x64) is in c:\hadoop\bin\
downloaded from http://www.eaiesb.com/blogs/?tag=setup-spark-on-windows

I run following command after create directory *C:\tmp\hive*

> C:\hadoop\bin\winutils.exe chmod 777 C:\tmp\hive

java version:

> java version "1.8.0_162"
>   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_162-b12)
>   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.162-b12, mixed mode)

scala version:

> Scala code runner version 2.12.5 -- Copyright 2002-2018, LAMP/EPFL and Lightbend, Inc.

I run Spark for the first time, so maybe I skipped some configuration steps? Please help.

Comment: `spark://HeartbeatReceiver@Silierin_Y510P:4391` is not valid Spark master URL. Accepted format is `spark://host:port`

Comment: You need to remove the @ symbol from your windows hostname

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, but it was solved by setting **SPARK_LOCAL_HOSTNAME=localhost**

Answer (score 4):

Looks like the host name has underscore got this issue.
https://jira.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-24192

Answer (score 3):

sparkConfig.set("spark.driver.host","localhost") solved my issue

Answer (score 1):

My problem was the name of my computer Spark on Windows does not work if your computer name contains certain symbols such as "@" or "_"

Comment: As soon as I renamed the machine to remove the underscore , it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

same issue for me in Windows 11. Renamed hostname without underscore and it works properly.

Env:

- spark-2.4.6-bin-hadoop2.7
- Winutils : https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils/blob/master/hadoop-2.7.1/bin/winutils.exe
- Copy winutils.exe in %SPARK_HOME%\bin directory

Hope it will help.